# How to loop through full result set using foreach container in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I encounter an issue when trying to use SSIS to retrieve a full result set from excel file.

I got two variables

[image: image description]

Here is the dashboard in control flow
[image: image description]

@CriteriaResult returns the ADO Recordset
[image: image description]

@CriteriaID is the variable I try to loop through under the object I just returned
[image: image description]

I encounter the error:The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::CriteriaID" differs from the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.

My data is a column: 1,2,3A,3B,3C...

Online reference told me to use script task to change the convert object(@CriteriaResult) so I can use the data inside of it.

My VBA code is:

```
Public Sub Main()    
Dim dt As Data.DataTable    
Dim ds As Data.DataSet = CType(Dts.Variables("User::CriteriaID").Value, DataSet)    
dt = ds.Tables(0)       
Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success    
End Sub
```

May I know how should I revise my code to make it works?

Comment: I don't understand very well your approach. I think that it's much simple to import data from Excel into a Recordset and then make a Foreach Loop on recordset variable with ADO Iterator

Comment: What kind of data is in the first column of the sheet?   What does the "General" tab of your foreach loop container look like?

Comment: Hi Tab, my data is a column of strings, like this: 1,2,3A,3B,3C

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach to iterate with an ADO enumerator:
1. Import to recordset with Data Flow Task
[image]
2. Iterate in ForEach with ADO Enumarator to recordset object variable
[image]
3. Each iteration saves record value to a variable
[image]

This is the package screenshot
[image]

Comment: Thanks, although different from your approach, I actually got a recordset as well and I'm trying to use ADO Enumarator to loop through it in a foreach container. However, this system error occurs at the loop step: The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::CriteriaID" differs from the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object. So I'm trying to use a script task to make the recordset readable.

Comment: Just set everything to type object, and SSIS will auto change the type to the correct one.