# For Each Loop SSIS. Dependent on SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, foreach-loop-container

1. I have an SSIS package which checks for the unprocessed file present in a tracking table and then processed it. Till date only one file would come in and we would process it and as such the process was designed accordingly.
2. However now multiple files can come in one go and we store those multiple files in the tracking table and we have a column which keeps a track of the unprocessed file.

I am trying to use the For Each loop to process all the unprocessed file. So I get the count of the unprocessed files and would like to simply tun the Point 1 by passing a parameter to the step 1 but I have not been successful in doing it using Foreach From Variable Enumerator. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Using a For Each Loop to iterate through table rows is all over the internet. I just referenced this link in a question yesterday: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i think the same link is provided in the answer below (first link) :)

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say here:   " tun the Point 1 by passing a parameter to the step 1"

Comment: @TabAlleman he need to get file pathes stored in db table and loop over result and process these files inside the loop

Comment: @Sunil is the issue solved? have you tried the provided answer? if so why not giving a feedback or accepting it?

Comment: @Yahfoufi the issue is solved. Actually I am still learning SSIS. I did look more into it and found that For Each Loop and For Loop have different concepts. What I was trying to achieve should have been done by For Loop and not For Each Loop. And as Hadi mentioned below I have to use System.Object in For Each loop for it to work.

Comment: @Sunil so you have to write your own answer or accept/upvote the current one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the following steps:

1. Add an Execute SQL Task to get unprocessed files and store the resultset inside a variable of type `System.Object`
2. Add a Foreach loop container, change the type to `ADO enumerator` and select the variable as source
3. In the variable mapping tab map the result (each file path) to a variable of type string
4. Inside the foreach loop container add a dataflow task that contains the Flat File source and implement the processing logic you need
5. Add a flat file connection manager define the columns
6. Click on the flat file connection manager, press F4 to show the property tab, go to expression.
7. Select the connectionstring property and use the variable that holds the filepath as expression

**Detailed articles**

- [Implementing Foreach Looping Logic in SSIS](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/amp/)
- [Looping Through a Result Set with the ForEach Loop](http://blog.pragmaticworks.com/looping-through-a-result-set-with-the-foreach-loop?hs_amp=true)
- [Using SSIS to Loop Over Result Set and Dynamically Generate Output Files](https://coldlogics.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/using-ssis-to-dynamically-create-data-files-from-a-full-result-set/amp/)
- [How to loop through full result set using foreach container in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553777/how-to-loop-through-full-result-set-using-foreach-container-in-ssis)